# Combining CASE Statements in SQL

Tags: sql, case

What I am trying to do is combine (2) CASE statements that each return a SUM and then take the SUM of those results. Here's what I have so far:

```
COUNT((
  CASE (COUNT(table.CODE))
    WHEN 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE SUM(
      CASE table.CODE
        WHEN '100'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END)) (
  CASE (COUNT(table.CODE))
    WHEN 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE (SUM(
      CASE table.CODE
        WHEN '50'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END))))
|| AS Total Code
```

I think I'm over-complicating this. The error I am receiving is Missing Keyword (at the beginning of the 2nd CASE statement). Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, is it mysql or oracle11g?  You have tags for both.

Comment: mysql was an accident... forgot to remove it

Comment: Now it's tagged as `mysql`, not `oracle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an overload of parentheticals, you might find it helpful to go overboard with indention to spot problems:

```
COUNT
    (
        (
            CASE (COUNT(table.CODE))
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0
                ELSE SUM
                    (
                        CASE table.CODE
                            WHEN '100'
                                THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                    )
             <--Should be an END here?-->
        ) <--What is happening here-->
        (
            CASE (COUNT(table.CODE))
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 
                    (
                        SUM
                            (
                                CASE table.CODE
                                    WHEN '50'
                                        THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                END
                            )
                    )
             <--Should be an END here?-->
        )
    )
    || AS Total Code
```

You can see that there are two CASE statements butted up against each other with no operator to make any sense of it.

You might also spot that your first and third `CASE` are not closed with an `END`, which is what MySQL is balking about.

Lastly, that double-bar in MySQL is an "OR" operator. But you are not OR'ing anything... Not sure what the plan was here.

Ultimately, though, I think you are going to run into problems Counting a Sum in the same query. You may have to move those `SUM(CASE...END)` bits into a subquery and then doing the `COUNT` outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over the answers to my questions, this is what I came up with:

```
CASE (COUNT(table.CODE))
    WHEN 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE ((SUM(
      CASE table.CODE
        WHEN '100' 
        THEN 1
        WHEN '50'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END))
  END) AS Value5
```

I'm cleaning up old code so I didn't completely understand what I was looking at because its all over the place. This is a lot cleaner and I'm positive that I am getting desired response now.